# Selenium / Python - target a "loading" gif and perform action upon the .gif disappearing?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am working on automating the testing of some of my company's internal software.  Upon a search, there is small spinner appearing on the page, and it disappears when the search is finished executing (code below).  During the search, the `rf-st-stop` has the style `"display: none;"`, and when the search is done `rf-st-start` has that style.  So, what I need, is to target that element and wait until it disappears, then execute my check to make sure the search is successful.  Thanks greatly!

```
<span class="rf-st-start" style="" >
    <img alt="processing" src="/images/loading.gif" ></img>
</span>
<span class="rf-st-stop" style="display: none;" ></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [selenium documentaion](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)
you can do something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
element = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "rf-st-stop")))
```

you can also use `EC.invisibility_of_element_located`

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.  I did see that `By.CLASS` should have been `By.CLASS_NAME` (see ['By' documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html]).  Please edit this in case it's referenced by someone else in the future.  Once again, thanks very much for your help.